# npm install package error with watchify on Mac OS El Capitan

Tags: macos, npm, watchify

I'm getting some error with `npm install --save-dev watchify` command when setting up React.js workspace. I'm not so sure what need to be done in order to resolve this problem.

Npm was installed via Homebrew.

Node version: v6.1.0
npm version: 3.8.6

```
$ npm install --save-dev watchify

> fsevents@1.0.12 install /Users/hungbui/Sites/reactjs/rightmove-react/node_modules/fsevents
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: socket hang up
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.onHangUp (_tls_wrap.js:1087:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.g (events.js:286:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:926:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 15.4.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.1.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/hungbui/Sites/reactjs/rightmove-react/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v48-darwin-x64/fse.node" "--module_name=fse" "--module_path=/Users/hungbui/Sites/reactjs/rightmove-react/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v48-darwin-x64"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/hungbui/Sites/reactjs/rightmove-react/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v6.1.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'node-gyp configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/hungbui/Sites/reactjs/rightmove-react/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v48-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/hungbui/Sites/reactjs/rightmove-react/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v48-darwin-x64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/hungbui/Sites/reactjs/rightmove-react/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 15.4.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.1.0/bin/node" "/Users/hungbui/Sites/reactjs/rightmove-react/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/hungbui/Sites/reactjs/rightmove-react/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v6.1.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.25
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute 'node-gyp configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/hungbui/Sites/reactjs/rightmove-react/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v48-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/hungbui/Sites/reactjs/rightmove-react/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v48-darwin-x64' (1)
npm WARN install:fsevents@1.0.12 fsevents@1.0.12 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm WARN install:fsevents@1.0.12 Exit status 1
```